# How do you avoid class name collisions?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I'm building a blog and add a class named "post" for the timeline posts. Then another developer comes in and creates a highlights section which also has a "post" class. All of a sudden we have a collision.

I usually solve this by nesting classes and not keeping anything "global" but from what I've understood it's not best practice:

```
.main .post {
    background-color: red;
}

.highlights .post {
    background-color: green;
}
```

When I inspect big sites CSS files I see loads of global class names for seemingly specific parts of the page so I'm really wondering how they solve it. Do they search and scan the whole project for a class name before adding it? What do they do if they want to add something which already exists? Renaming it just for the sake of it seems like a really bad practice if anything.

Comment: My oppinion and experience is that you SHOULD define global styles. Other developers should be able to use your definitions like a toolkit and without knowlege of special wrapping-classes. Just think of it like writing a new framework. Which names would be obvious for certain controls? Could i use my classes/partials in other projects with just copy and paste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The secret is to use some sort of framework/methodology that enforces discipline e.g. [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) or [BEM](http://bem.info/).

Comment: BEM has the most disgusting syntax I've ever seen

Comment: Totally agree and that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are several CSS classes naming conventions around and one of the most used is BEM (http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/). Take a look :)